# Alternating current net impedance

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance

I am trying to find net impedance using complex numbers
using  $\frac{Z_1 Z_2}{Z_1+Z_2}$
where $Z_1=R_1-X_C$  and $Z_2=R_2+X_L$.

I am confused why this formula is valid here since it is for parallel combination of resistance.

[image]

Comment: Z1 and Z2 are parallel, R1 and C are in a row as R2 and L

Answer (score 2):

> I am confused why this formula is valid here since it is for parallel
> combination of resistance.

The formula is not just valid for a parallel combination of resistances. It is the formula for the general case of two parallel *impedances*. It only becomes

$$R_{eq}=\frac{R_{1}R_{2}}{R_{1}+R_{2}}$$

when the parallel impedances are purely resistive.

When inductors and capacitors are involved, be careful to use complex impedance. That is $X_C$ should be $-jX_C$, and $X_L$ should be $+jX_L$

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the voltage source as $V_i$. The current $I$ flowing from $V1$ will split within the two branches, one formed by $R_1, X_C$ giving an impedance $Z_1 = R_1 + jX_C$ and the other by $R_2, X_L$ with impedance $Z_2 = R_2 + jX_L $. By Kirchhoff law of currents:
$$ I = I_1 + I_2 $$
Where $I_1, I_2$ are the currents flowing throught $Z_1$ and $Z_2$ respectively.
Since $Z_1$ and $Z_2$ are in parallel, they share the same voltage applied ($V_i$). So:
$$ I = I_1 + I_2 = \frac{V_i}{Z_1} + \frac{V_i}{Z_2} = V_i \left(\frac{1}{Z_1} + \frac{1}{Z_2} \right) $$
Dividing by $V_i$ we get
$$ \frac{I}{V_i} = \frac{1}{Z_{eq}} = \left(\frac{1}{Z_1} + \frac{1}{Z_2} \right)  $$
And rearranging:
$$ Z_{eq} = \frac{Z_1Z_1}{Z_1 + Z_2} $$
which is the usual formula used for asociating parallel impedances, and that reduces to your formula when you only have resistors.